# how to check if two Boolean? values are true in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Sample code:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
        val after = it.expectedArrivalDate?.after(today)
        val before = it.expectedArrivalDate?.before(tomorrow)
        after != null && before != null && after && before
    }.size
```

If `it.expectedArrivalDate` were not `nullable` I would write something like that:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
    it.expectedArrivalDate.after(today) && it.expectedArrivalDate.before(tomorrow)
}.size
```

Is it possible to simplify my code?

Comment: What results do you get for a date that is **after today and before tomorrow**?

Comment: smth like this (it.expectedArrivalDate?.after(today) ?? false) && (it.expectedArrivalDate?.before(tomorrow) ?? false) ?

Comment: Use `count` instead of `filter {...}.size` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to simplify that check.

Assuming that the type of `expectedArrivalDate` is `Date`, you could add `after` and `before` functions for the nullable Date type `Date?` that would return false if the instance is null, or call the original `after`/`before` functions if not null:

```
fun Date?.after(anotherDate: Date): Boolean = this?.after(anotherDate) ?: false
fun Date?.before(anotherDate: Date): Boolean = this?.before(anotherDate) ?: false
```

and leave your code as it is:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
    it.expectedArrivalDate.after(today) && it.expectedArrivalDate.before(tomorrow)
}.size
```

---

or you could just use the implementation directly in your code:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
    (it.expectedArrivalDate?.after(today) ?: false) && (it.expectedArrivalDate?.before(tomorrow) ?: false)
}.size
```

Comment: The solution with Elvis operator is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I personally was surprised that this priority is correct. I'd really prefer to write `(it.expectedArrivalDate?.after(today) ?: false) && ...`.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to extension functions or Elvis operators is simply `== true`.

In Java, where `==` compares references, that would be dangerous, as it would fail for any new Boolean instances.  But in Kotlin, `==` compares values using `.equals()` (after making the necessary null checks), so would handle that case perfectly well.

So your code could be:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
    it.expectedArrivalDate?.after(today) == true
    && it.expectedArrivalDate?.before(tomorrow) == true
}.size
```

Similarly, if you wanted `null` to count as `true`, you could use `!= false`.

It's arguably not the most elegant solution, but it's probably the simplest!

Comment: This *is* the most elegant and easy-to-read solution, in my opinion. By the way, in the OP, `expectedArrivalDate` is nullable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks; now corrected.  I hesitate to recommend this because it's not entirely obvious.  Here `?.` is a strong hint, but it's not always so clear that the LHS could be null, and that the apparently-unnecessary comparison is to handle that case.  (I've spent so long removing _genuinely_ unnecessary such comparisons from other people's dodgy code, that it still seems like a code smell!)  — And even then, you still have to stop and think which way the null case will go.  So while it's clearly the shortest solution, it's not ideal.  Though probably none are!

Comment: @gidds thanks for your answer. Your code actually returns Boolean? instead of Boolean that is required by filter

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [variable re-declaration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27627?_ga=2.238359872.1914622045.1574231939-1545821892.1573386696) using `?:`

> variable re-declaration (and shadowing).
>
> ```
> fun leftPad(value: String, length: Int? = null, char: Char? = null): String {
>     val length = length ?: 4
>     val char = char ?: ' '
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be considered a simplification but as another option you can:

```
val todayCount = keyValue.value.filter {
    it.expectedArrivalDate?.takeIf{d -> d.after(today)}?.takeIf{d -> d.before(tomorrow)}?.let{true}?:false
}.size
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without an extension function: as all comparisons are based on the same field, you can actually map it while removing all nulls.

Here's a sample code with a dummy travel class so that you can see it compiles:

```
data class Travel(var expectedArrivalDate: Date? = null);

lateinit var keyValue: Map.Entry<String, List<Travel>>;
val today = Date.from(Instant.now())
val tomorrow = Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(86400))

val todayCount = keyValue.value.mapNotNull(Travel::expectedArrivalDate).count {
    it.after(today) && it.before(tomorrow)
}
```

Gets the solution down to 125 characters and gets close to the code you had in mind.