# How to check a nullable boolean in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

if I want to check a nullable `Boolean` I get a `type mismatch`

```
var bool: Boolean? = true

if(bool) 
  println("foo") 
else 
  println("bar")
```

because `Boolean is expected` not `Boolean?`

Comment: Related to (duplicate of?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974510/how-to-check-if-two-boolean-values-are-true-in-kotlin

Comment: Well, related maybe – but not so clear and easy to understand imho

Comment: Yes, but that question had _my_ answer, which was of course _incredibly_ clear and easy to understand :-)

Comment: True! But the example code was not :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of Boolean? in if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830904/use-of-boolean-in-if-expression)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to treat `null` case differently from either `true` or `false`:

```
when(bool) {
    null -> println("null")
    true -> println("foo")
    false -> println("bar")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `Boolean.equals()`

```
var bool: Boolean? = null

if(true.equals(bool)) 
  println("foo") 
else 
  println("bar")
```

it is even possible to do this inline

```
var bool: Boolean? = null

if(true == bool) 
  println("foo") 
else 
  println("bar")
```

Or use *elvis nullable boolean check*

```
var bool: Boolean? = null

if(bool ?: false) 
  println("foo") 
else 
  println("bar")
```

Comment: The reason for this is that a nullable Boolean? has three states (true/false/ null) and not just two (true/false), so you have to check against true or false explicitly.

Comment: No good reason to use `equals` here, `==` calls `equals` but treats `null` correctly so you can safely write `bool == true`. I'd still go with the last option because it makes the intention clear and doesn't _look_ like an antipattern like `== true` does.

Comment: The 2nd example here is the one I think Intellij IDEA Kotlin plugin recommends as idiomatic.

Comment: IMO, the second example is far easier to reason about than the third, although I'd flip it around to `bool == true`. `== true` is an immediate indicator we're dealing with a nullable since it's idiomatic. It would only make me pause if I knew the author was a beginner programmer.

Comment: Yes, apparently so (for `bool == true` over `bool ?: false`). The motivation is https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide/issues/18#issuecomment-225417634 and there's also some useful discussion in https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-the-idiom-for-checking-nullable-booleans-helpful/8238

Answer (score -1):

When you have nullable type my suggestion is this:

If you put nullable for a reason it means that variable could be nullable, so before do anything you have to check if it's not null.

```
 val bool: Boolean? = null

     if(bool != null) {
         if(bool){
             println("foo")
         } else {
             println("foo")
         }
    } else {
    println("variable non instancied yet")
   }
```

Comment: You will get `Smart cast to 'Boolean' is impossible, because 'bool' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time`

Comment: I'm not get anything like that. Could you be more precise?

Comment: @karlsebal In the case shown in your question `bool` is a local variable, not a property, so couldn't be changed.

Comment: I see. I ran it as a scratch file in intellij and got the error mentioned

Comment: I didn't im running it in android studio as you